# how to "browse for folder" in html/javaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
<input type="file"> only allows the user to browse for files.
```

How about "browse for folder" dialog? Can html/javascript do that? I
couldn't find any syntax for that. If not, please advise what are the
other approaches.

please advise. thanks!!

Comment: I think that if you are trying to upload the contents of a folder you have resort to multiple `<input>`'s... Still, +1

Comment: Why would you want that? Then you could just ask the user to type the name of the folder!

Comment: can you tell a bit more about why you have to select the folder to save the file? Can't we just select file/files directly?

Comment: After your comments, this question doesn't make any sense. Inputs are for uploading data, not downloading!

Comment: have a look at this link dude http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5201 im sure there is an option

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're building a website, there is no other option to save a file on the clients computer then to let him/her download it, which will (as stated in my comment) go to his download folder, or present him **a dialog to let him choose a *directory***.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple file select dialog with flash, but for folder on client machine, that needs to go with Java applet at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`<input type="file" webkitdirectory multiple/>`

Note: "webkitdirectory" won't work on IE, It will works as "browse for file" dialog".